# Как сделать бэкап(pg_dump), за исключением некоторых таблиц?

Tags: postgresql

Выполняю pg_dump, но он сохраняет всю БД. 
А мне нужно чтобы таблица log, не сохранялась, так как содержит много данных для отладки. 
Именно данных таблицы, но не структуры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там есть директива [`--exclude-table-data`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html), `pg_dump` не будет сохранять данные таблицы.